# Setting Git in Rstudio

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I'm trying to launch Git on Rstudio. 
I was following this instructions:

http://www.geo.uzh.ch/microsite/reproducible_research/post/rr-rstudio-git/

I installed git and I have the path for its executable file on my disk.
I set this in global options.
Unfortunately after having R-studio restarted () the Git icon did not appear, so basically Git is not working.

Comment: Can you confirm git is install properly? Open a command line and type `git --version`

Comment: I got such a response:
$ git --version
git version 2.17.0.windows.1

So I think it is properly installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in RStudio:

1. Tools > Global Options > Git / SVN;
2. point to the location of your Git executable:

[image]

Comment: I've done this. And I tried three different .exe files. But it did not work out.

Comment: Maybe a good old uninstall and reinstall then? What happens if you try to create a new RStudio project from a repo?

Comment: Could you explain what you did do the second time for it to work in order to help out people in the same situation?

Comment: The problem is I did nothing. I restarted R many times but it did not work. Then I started doing something else and I came back to the problem and luckily it turned out to be working.